# Why did Madara use Wood Clones to manifest Susano'o while fighting the 5 Kage instead of Shadow Clones?

Tags: naruto

Was it because:

- Shadow Clones can't perform Susano'o, but Wood Clones can?
- Wood Clones are stronger/better than Shadow Clones?
- Madara couldn't perform the Shadow Clone Technique?
- Of any other reason not mentioned above?

Comment: I think the answer is Madara wanted to test out some jutsu mainly hashiram's it's the only reason he used them because 1. Shadow clones perform any jutsu user know ex:- Naruto rasengan 2 . Madara might know about shadow clone because tobiram can perform it & we know Madara has a sharingan 3 . I think wood clone isn't different than a shadow clone but maybe small difference in endurance.

Answer (score 1):

In the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wood_Clone_Technique), it is mentioned that

> Wood Clone Technique, unlike other clone techniques, **do not disappear when hit** and it is able to take damage to a certain degree. 'This, according to Madara Uchiha, makes it *the perfect clone technique that only he with his dōjutsu was able to see through*.' This happened in **Chapter 577**.

This was most likely the reason why he preferred using wood clones. The two other possibilities you mentioned above are not possible and here are the reasons:

1. The first possibility is wrong since both [Shadow Clones](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Clone_Technique) and [Wood Clones](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wood_Clone_Technique) **can perform jutsu**.
2. The third possibility is wrong since Madara Uchiha is listed as **one of the Shadow Clone users**. [He even used it to fake his death](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shadow_Clone_Technique#Trivia).